# Can't fix error "The manadatory svg POST parameter is undefined." with HighCharts export (PHP/CURL)

Tags: php, curl, highcharts

I've used HighCharts for years already and out of the blue, exporting charts to PNG, JPG and so on doesn't work anymore. I export to http://export.highcharts.com/ using cURL the way I should:

`curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);`
`curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);`
`curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);`

Where $fields_string is also formatted well and INCLUDES the svg= parameter.

Why does it keep giving me back the error:
"The manadatory svg POST parameter is undefined."????

I've tried all sorts of things, but why does it not work anymore? I check on the HighCharts website, but there... they do work.

var_dump() $fields_string is:

```
string(7069) "svg=<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="700" height="422"><defs><clipPath id="highcharts-5"><rect rx="0" ry="0" fill="none" x="0" y="0" width="632" height="275" stroke-width="0.000001"></rect></clipPath></defs><rect rx="5" ry="5" fill="#FFFFFF" x="0" y="0" width="700" height="422" stroke-width="0.000001" stroke="#4572A7"></rect><text x="350" y="25" style="font-family:verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:16px;color:#3e576f;fill:#3e576f;" text-anchor="middle" class="highcharts-title" ><tspan x="350">Test</tspan></text><g class="highcharts-grid" ></g><g class="highcharts-grid" ><path d="M 58 330.5 L 690 330.5" fill="none" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1" ></path><path d="M 58 239.5 L 690 239.5" fill="none" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1" ></path><path d="M 58 147.5 L 690 147.5" fill="none" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1" ></path><path d="M 58 55.5 L 690 55.5" fill="none" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1" ></path></g><g class="highcharts-series-group" ><g class="highcharts-series" clip-path="url(#highcharts-5)" visibility="visible" transform="translate(58,55)"><rect rx="0" ry="0" fill="none" x="82.5" y="16.5" width="149" height="257" stroke-width="5" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" r="0" stroke-opacity="0.05" transform="translate(1,1)"></rect><rect rx="0" ry="0" fill="none" x="82.5" y="16.5" width="149" height="257" stroke-width="3" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" r="0" stroke-opacity="0.1" transform="translate(1,1)"></rect><rect rx="0" ry="0" fill="none" x="82.5" y="16.5" width="149" height="257" stroke-width="1" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" r="0" stroke-opacity="0.15000000000000002" transform="translate(1,1)"></rect><rect rx="0" ry="0" fill="#4572a7" x="82.5" y="16.5" width="149" height="257" stroke-width="1" stroke="#FFFFFF" r="0"></rect><rect rx="0" ry="0" fill="none" x="398.5" y="75.5" width="149" height="198" stroke-width="5" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" r="0" stroke-opacity="0.05" transform="translate(1,1)"></rect><rect rx="0" ry="0" fill="none" x="398.5" y="75.5" width="149" height="198" stroke-width="3" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" r="0" stroke-opacity="0.1" transform="translate(1,1)"></rect><rect rx="0" ry="0" fill="none" x="398.5" y="75.5" width="149" height="198" stroke-width="1" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" r="0" stroke-opacity="0.15000000000000002" transform="translate(1,1)"></rect><rect rx="0" ry="0" fill="#aa4643" x="398.5" y="75.5" width="149" height="198" stroke-width="1" stroke="#FFFFFF" r="0"></rect></g></g><g class="highcharts-data-labels" visibility="visible" transform="translate(58,55)"><text x="158" y="10" style="font-family:verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:11px;color:#4572a7;line-height:14px;font-weight:bold;fill:#4572a7;" text-anchor="middle" ><tspan x="158">56.42%</tspan></text><text x="474" y="69" style="font-family:verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:11px;color:#4572a7;line-height:14px;font-weight:bold;fill:#4572a7;" text-anchor="middle" ><tspan x="474">43.58%</tspan></text></g><g class="highcharts-legend" transform="translate(274,381)"><rect rx="5" ry="5" fill="none" x="0.5" y="0.5" width="151" height="25" stroke-width="1" stroke="#909090" visibility="visible"></rect><text x="30" y="18" style="font-family:verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;cursor:pointer;color:#3e576f;fill:#3e576f;" ><tspan x="30">Performance Ratio</tspan></text><rect rx="2" ry="2" fill="#4572a7" x="9.5" y="7.5" width="16" height="12" stroke-width="1" stroke="#FFFFFF" r="0"></rect></g><g class="highcharts-axis" ><text x="216" y="344.19704790557563" style="font-family:verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:11px;color:#666;line-height:14px;font:normal 9px sans-serif;fill:#666;" text-anchor="end" transform="rotate(-35 216 344)"><tspan x="216">Piano</tspan></text><text x="532" y="344.19704790557563" style="font-family:verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:11px;color:#666;line-height:14px;font:normal 9px sans-serif;fill:#666;" text-anchor="end" transform="rotate(-35 532 344)"><tspan x="532">MagneticOne</tspan></text><path d="M 374.5 330.19704790557563 L 374.5 335.19704790557563" fill="none" stroke="#C0D0E0" stroke-width="1"></path><path d="M 690.5 330.19704790557563 L 690.5 335.19704790557563" fill="none" stroke="#C0D0E0" stroke-width="1"></path></g><g class="highcharts-axis" ><text x="50" y="335.29704790557565" style="font-family:verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:11px;width:296px;color:#666;line-height:14px;fill:#666;" text-anchor="end"><tspan x="50">0</tspan></text><text x="50" y="243.630381238909" style="font-family:verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:11px;width:296px;color:#666;line-height:14px;fill:#666;" text-anchor="end"><tspan x="50">20</tspan></text><text x="50" y="151.9637145722423" style="font-family:verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:11px;width:296px;color:#666;line-height:14px;fill:#666;" text-anchor="end"><tspan x="50">40</tspan></text><text x="50" y="60.29704790557562" style="font-family:verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:11px;width:296px;color:#666;line-height:14px;fill:#666;" text-anchor="end"><tspan x="50">60</tspan></text></g><text x="26" y="192.5" style="font-family:verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;color:#6d869f;font-weight:bold;fill:#6d869f;" transform="rotate(270 26 192)" text-anchor="middle"><tspan x="26">Combined Performance</tspan></text><path d="M 58 330.5 L 690 330.5" fill="none" stroke="#C0D0E0" stroke-width="1" ></path><g class="highcharts-tooltip" visibility="hidden"><rect rx="5" ry="5" fill="none" x="2" y="2" width="0" height="0" stroke-width="5" fill-opacity="0.85" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke-opacity="0.05" transform="translate(1,1)"></rect><rect rx="5" ry="5" fill="none" x="2" y="2" width="0" height="0" stroke-width="3" fill-opacity="0.85" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke-opacity="0.1" transform="translate(1,1)"></rect><rect rx="5" ry="5" fill="none" x="2" y="2" width="0" height="0" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="0.85" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke-opacity="0.15000000000000002" transform="translate(1,1)"></rect><rect rx="5" ry="5" fill="rgb(255,255,255)" x="2" y="2" width="0" height="0" stroke-width="2" fill-opacity="0.85"></rect><text x="2" y="14" style="font-family:verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;color:#333333;padding:0;white-space:nowrap;fill:#333333;" ><tspan x="2"> </tspan></text></g><text x="690" y="417" style="font-family:verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:10px;cursor:pointer;color:#909090;fill:#909090;" text-anchor="end" ><tspan x="690"> </tspan></text><g class="highcharts-tracker" transform="translate(58,55)"><rect rx="0" ry="0" fill="rgb(192,192,192)" x="82" y="16" width="150" height="258" stroke-width="0.000001" fill-opacity="0.000001" visibility="visible" style="cursor:pointer;"></rect><rect rx="0" ry="0" fill="rgb(192,192,192)" x="398" y="75" width="150" height="199" stroke-width="0.000001" fill-opacity="0.000001" visibility="visible" style="cursor:pointer;"></rect></g></svg>&filename=chart&type=image/png"
```

When I do echo the value of the svg, I see a perfect SVG image in my browser.

Comment: `var_dump($fields_string);` and put the results in the question details.

Comment: Edited the question. Note, I've also tried urlencode() all parameters but that resulted in different errors.

Comment: Try giving the POST fields to CURL as an array, and let it do the encoding for you. `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('svg' => $svgContent, 'filename' => 'chart', 'type' => 'image/png'))`

Comment: Yea, the HTML in that string is likely causing you problems. Follow @Colin's advice.

Comment: Ok, this is working for at least a bit. Thanks! Some charts work now but some still don't. Now, I get a different error saying it can't convert the svg image. Even though when I use the same SVG in other online tools, it can.

I'll update here when I find out what's wrong this time but thansk for the array tip!

Comment: Turns out that it has to to with an embedded logo in the charts. That used to work perfectly but probably, Highcharts changed something so now it doesn't work anymore. We removed the logo and now it all works again.